# Core Data Read-Only storage

Tags: core-data, ios7, xcode6, persistent-storage

I am looking at the tutorial at this address:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-core-data-stack--cms-20926
in order to refresh my Core Data basic understanding and to solve some problem I am having right now.

I would like to have a read-only store. Using what is in the bundle of my app, as I used to do.
But it seems like it is not working any more with Xcode 6.

I have read about the subject on the net, but cannot make it work at this point.

Here is the relevant code:

```
NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Core_Data" withExtension:@"sqlite"];

if (defaultStoreURL) {
    NSURL *storeURL=defaultStoreURL;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
            NSLog(@"RO-DB NOT FOUND");
        } else NSLog(@"RO-DB FOUND");

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:nil
                                                             URL:storeURL
                                                         options:@{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{ @"journal_mode":@"DELETE" },
                                                                   NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]}
                                                           error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@“WE HAVE A PROBLEM!!!”);
    }

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

…. it does not work.

The addPersistentStoreWithType method call crashes with the message:
2014-12-03 01:06:22.759 Core Data[7509:257741] CoreData: error: (14) I/O error for database at /Users/meHere/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B9E89312-6E93-44FC-B7B7-1E04D4C9CK6A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7A789123-72D6-4B0A-BB05-F017A74A9497/Core Data.app/Core_Data.sqlite.  SQLite error code:14, 'unable to open database file'
.....

Comment: That's a generic SQLite error, so it's almost certainly unrelated to the read-only flag. Are you sure the file actually exists at that location?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I did some test to take care of that.
And I just modified the text of the question to show this.

Comment: Instead of using the file in the bundle. if I use the one in applicationDocumentsDirectory, it works, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with the code, and using Xcode 6 doesn't affect whether it would work. That implies that something's wrong with the file, something that SQLite doesn't like.

Comment: Well, I just copied the Core_Data.sqlite file to the bundle, the same way I always do. And under the debugger I can see that the file is present inside the bundle. But I read that things have changed due to WAL stuff. I suspect this where I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, if you don't copy the journal files, you don't get a useable SQLite file.

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem at the moment in an app I am building. Have found out that the error is gone when the directory is writable or the readonly flag is false. 
Have read somewhere the DB might be corrupt and therefore needs to write right away when the app starts to fix it. However I am still looking into this...

Comment: Tom. What do you mean by "journal files"?
If you mean "Core_Data.sqlite-wal", I just tried copying the file into the project, the same way I copy Core_Data.sqlite; but it does not make any difference. The problem is still there.